# Tagging control that was created in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

Many will find this question quite trivial, but since I'm quite new on iOS and COcoa programming, such questions simply arise.
So, I have validation methods that need to know which control has called them, because validation rules depend on specific control.
I know how to tag control with UIView tag property, but this works if I would create controls programatically. 
How do I do this if I created controls in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select any element in your view hierarchy in IB and open the Attributes Inspector (Cmd+1), you should see an entry "Tag" towards the bottom of the list (right below "Mode", "Alpha" and "Background"). That's the property you've been setting programmatically.